# how to work check box event for particular internal frame in swing

Tags: java, swing, state, jcheckbox

When I select/enable the check box for particular Intenalframe then perform related action.But,when create another new Internalframe the previous action is not applicable for this.I perform Any checkbox Action that is particular to that Internalframe only not common for all.In my code have Viewlinenumbers checkbox menuitem.I want to set the above behaviour to Linenumbers.Check it once.

Sample code:

```
public class ResetItems extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    JTextField status;
    int i=0;
    JTextPane currentTextPane,lnNum;
    JScrollPane scrollPane;

    public ResetItems() {
        initComponents();
        lineNumbers.setSelected(false);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        tabbedPane = new javax.swing.JTabbedPane();
        menuBar = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
        file = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        create = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        lineNumbers = new javax.swing.JCheckBoxMenuItem();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        file.setText("File");

        create.setText("Create");
        create.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                createActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        file.add(create);

        lineNumbers.setSelected(true);
        lineNumbers.setText("LineNumbers");
        lineNumbers.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                lineNumbersActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        file.add(lineNumbers);

        menuBar.add(file);

        setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(tabbedPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 279, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(tabbedPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 279, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void createActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        final JInternalFrame internalFrame = new JInternalFrame("");
        i++;
        internalFrame.setName("Doc "+i);
        internalFrame.setClosable(true);
        internalFrame.setAutoscrolls(true);
        currentTextPane=new JTextPane();
        currentTextPane.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Miriam Fixed", 0, 13));
        tabbedPane.add(internalFrame);
        tabbedPane.add(internalFrame);
        tabbedPane.setSelectedIndex(i-1);
        currentTextPane.setCaretPosition(0);
        scrollPane=new JScrollPane(currentTextPane);
        internalFrame.add(scrollPane);
        internalFrame.setSize(internalFrame.getMaximumSize());
        internalFrame.pack();
        internalFrame.setVisible(true);
    }                                      

    private void lineNumbersActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            

    }                                           

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ResetItems.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ResetItems.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ResetItems.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ResetItems.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new ResetItems().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem create;
    private javax.swing.JMenu file;
    private javax.swing.JCheckBoxMenuItem lineNumbers;
    private javax.swing.JMenuBar menuBar;
    private javax.swing.JTabbedPane tabbedPane;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: you can to add JTextPane inside JScrollPane directly as a new tab in JTabbedPane, JInternalFrame is designated to be laid in JFrame/JDesktopPane

Comment: i modified with your suggestions but problem same as the above mentioned.